# Is there a way to detect if experimental_compile is True from inside a function

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a tensorflow op which works in the non-XLA case but does not work using XLA.

If the op is used inside a function decorated with `@tf.function(experimental_compile=True)`, then tensorflow gives an error, since the op does not have an implementation using XLA.

The solution that I want to implement is to somehow detect inside the op implementation whether or not the user has specified `@tf.function(experimental_compile=True)`.

So if the user has not specified this, then I would use a custom GPU non-XLA implementation. One the other hand, if the user has specified this, I would simply use the default implementation and let XLA itself implement the op fusing optimizations on that.

So does anyone know if it is possible to detect inside the op implementation whether or not the op has been used inside a function with the `@tf.function(experimental_compile=True)` decorator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

If you check the tensorflow source code for the [`tf.function`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.4.1/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py#L1598) implementation, you can see that it is a wrapper that returns a
[`Function`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.4.1/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py#L550) object. This object exposes `_experimental_compile` to your method when you decorate it.  So you can check if your method has this attribute, inside your method definition, and then write conditionals on whether or not to execute your xla sensitive op.

**Examples**:

```py
# relevant packages

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.platform import test as test_lib


# a fake op that doesn't have an xla implementation
def xla_sensitive_op(tensor):
    """An op that won't run with experimental compiling enabled."""
    # do tensorflow stuff
    return tensor


# a fake op that has an xla implementation
def xla_compliant_op(tensor):
    """An op that will run with experimental compiling enabled."""
    # do tensorflow stuff
    return 2 * tensor
```

Test an undecorated function

```py
def maybe_decorated_func(tensor):
    compile_on = None
    if hasattr(maybe_decorated_func, '_experimental_compile'):
        compile_on = maybe_decorated_func._experimental_compile
    if compile_on:
        return xla_compliant_op(tensor)
    else:
        return xla_sensitive_op(tensor)


class TestXLASensitiveOp(test_lib.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.tensor = tf.constant([1, 2, 3])

    def test_func_is_not_decorated(self):
        self.assertAllEqual(
            maybe_decorated_func(self.tensor),
            tf.constant([1, 2, 3]))  # <= executes 2nd branch of if/else


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_lib.main()

# [ RUN      ] TestXLASensitiveOp.test_func_is_not_decorated
# [       OK ] TestXLASensitiveOp.test_func_is_not_decorated
```

Test a decorated function, but without experimental compile enabled

```py
@tf.function
def maybe_decorated_func(tensor):
    compile_on = None
    if hasattr(maybe_decorated_func, '_experimental_compile'):
        compile_on = maybe_decorated_func._experimental_compile
    if compile_on:
        return xla_compliant_op(tensor)
    else:
        return xla_sensitive_op(tensor)


class TestXLASensitiveOp(test_lib.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.tensor = tf.constant([1, 2, 3])

    def test_func_is_decorated_but_no_compile(self):
        self.assertAllEqual(
            maybe_decorated_func(self.tensor),
            tf.constant([1, 2, 3]))  # <= executes 2nd branch of if/else


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_lib.main()

# [ RUN      ] TestXLASensitiveOp.test_func_is_decorated_but_no_compile
# [       OK ] TestXLASensitiveOp.test_func_is_decorated_but_no_compile
```

Test a decorated function with experimental compile enabled

```py
@tf.function(experimental_compile=True)
def maybe_decorated_func(tensor):
    compile_on = None
    if hasattr(maybe_decorated_func, '_experimental_compile'):
        compile_on = maybe_decorated_func._experimental_compile
    if compile_on:
        return xla_compliant_op(tensor)
    else:
        return xla_sensitive_op(tensor)


class TestXLASensitiveOp(test_lib.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.tensor = tf.constant([1, 2, 3])

    def test_func_is_decorated_with_compile(self):
        self.assertAllEqual(
            maybe_decorated_func(self.tensor),
            tf.constant([2, 4, 6]))  # <= executes 1st branch of if/else


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_lib.main()

# [ RUN      ] TestXLASensitiveOp.test_func_is_decorated_with_compile
# [       OK ] TestXLASensitiveOp.test_func_is_decorated_with_compile
```

Comment: Thanks.  But in my case, xla_sensitive_op would be called directly by the user inside a function that may or may not be tf.function decorated.  So is there a way to detect this from within xla_sensitive_op?

Comment: I don't understand how that is different that what I've written above.

Comment: in your example, xla_sensitive_op is part of the TF interface and if I add a boolean to detect whether or not experimental compile is enabled, that changes the interface.  I don't think people would like that.  I don't understand how to make this work in my use case.